# Sharepoint Online 2013 Page Content Snippet

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have to divs in my page layout which should both have a title and content.
When i add a page content snippet to each of them i get the same content in all of them
How do i add multiple page content snippets on that page, so that each is editable independently

Answer (score 0):

Got it, just add new content types of type publishing

Comment: Can you please add more details regarding how to do what you propose? Your answer is not helpful for other readers right now